# XSS bypass in url

Tags: xss, reflected-xss, bug-bounty

I have a website: [https://bugbounty.com/test/"injection](https://bugbounty.com/test/%22injection) inside js", but `"` is escaped with `\` and I'm trying to inject `</script><script>alert()` but `https://bugbounty.com/test/</script><script>alert()` redirects me to a 404 page because of `/`, I tried encoding `/` as `%2f` but I get the same results.

Do you have any idea how to bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean specifically that the URL content is injected into the document, specifically inside of a string that is inside of an inline Javascript block (or possibly event handler). The string which you want to break out of is delimited with `"` characters. You have already tried terminating the string by injecting a `"` yourself, but this fails because it gets backslash-escaped. You have already tried terminating the script block (from within the string, which causes a JS syntax error but that's OK) and starting a new one, but the injection fails if it contains a forward slash even if it's URL-encoded (implying that the server URL-decodes before checking for banned characters). I assume you've verified that it's the slash specifically causing the problem, rather than e.g. the less-than signs (404 does suggest that it's parsing it as a path component).

The most likely path to success right here would be to escape the backslash. If you include `\"` in your injection, what happens? The correct thing to do would be to either escape both characters (resulting in the JS containing `\\\"`) or reject the request (404 or some other 4xx error or just a redirection or ignoring the injection entirely). If the site doesn't do one of those things, then you can probably terminate the string and be in business.

If you can inject a newline (e.g. using %0A) then then also will terminate a `"`-delimited string, but unfortunately also causes a syntax error and you won't be able to escape from that unless you can start a new script block (which it sounds like you can't). If the [string were delimited using backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) then you could try a template injection, but it sounds like it isn't. As such, if the escape-the-backslash plan doesn't work and you can't find a way to close the script block either, then this injection point might not actually be exploitable.